# Force Netbeans to use UTF8 on files outside project

Tags: netbeans, utf-8, character-encoding

Is there any way to tell Netbeans 7.4, that it should use `UTF-8` encoding, no matter what? Also for files outside any project and also for files, where character coding can't be determined?

Netbeans 7.4 (and earlier) always uses `UTF-8` for all files in any project and always *not* uses it (uses `ANSI` or something else), when opening / saving file from outside any project. Since entire world goes toward `UTF-8`, I find this as a huge bug, though dev team claims, that this is design element.

No matter, how you call this, this is an unbelievable nightmare for me. When I want to use Netbeans to quickly edit some project-less PHP file, I always end up with messed national characters. Even if I save file in (`ANSI`?) Netbeans, open it in Notepad++, convert to `UTF-8` and then reopen in Netbeans, it again forces some strange encoding on this file (`ANSI`?) and all national characters are messed. I tried converting file (in Notepad++) to both `UTF-8` and `UTF-8 without BOM`. No effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem. Finally I found solution:

1. locate and edit your netbeans.conf file, for me it was located here:

`C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\etc\netbeans.conf`

2. find netbeans_default_options line and add this new option to end:

`-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`

Comment: Thank for your answer. I'm accepting it, since it is the only one here. However, I can't check, if your solution works, because I finally got rid of slow buggy Netbeans half a year ago and switch into lightning fast Sublime Text 3.